# Which letters will possibly have stress marks above them?

Tags: ударение, vowel

I'm writing a program that does many things, but one thing it needs to do is remove stress marks above Russian letters if there are any. Can someone tell me if these are all the letters that I will need to look for? Do capital letters ever have stress marks above them in sentences? Does ё ever have a stress mark above it?

аа́ ээ́ уу́ оо́ ыы́ яя́ ее́ юю́ ии́

Answer (score 6):

In Russian, stresses are used only in books for foreign learners, dictionaries and academic papers, when necessary.

If we're talking about Russian - and not Cyrillic in general - this kind of accentuation exist only for vowels, that is, for the exact list you mentioned: `а́`, `е́`, `и́`, `о́`, `у́`, `ы́`, `э́`, `ю́`, `я́`.  Yes, all these letters can be stress in the uppercase: `А́`, `Е́`, `И́`, `О́`, `У́`, `Ы́`, `Э́`, `Ю́`, `Я́`. And no, "ё" can never have a stress because apart from very rare and even specially constructed examples, "ё" is always stressed.

Answer (score 0):

Ударными буквы бывают только гласные: а, е, о, у, и, я, ю, э (ё - всегда  ударная)

Выделяются эти буквы голосом. Они будут иметь маркировку напряжения.

Например: де́рево, окно́, де́вочка, ёжик и др.